# The multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, using modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finite-fields, abelian-groups, principal-ideal-domains

I need to prove, specifically using modules over $\Bbb{Z}$, that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic. This is what I've done already:

The multiplicative group of a finite field is in particular an abelian group. Hence, a $\Bbb{Z}$-module. Because $\Bbb{Z}$ is a PID, we can write the multiplicative group as $$
\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^\times \cong \Bbb{Z}/(c_1) \oplus \ldots \oplus \Bbb{Z}/(c_k)
$$ with $c_1 \vert c_2 \vert \ldots \vert c_k$. Equivalently, $$
\Bbb{F}_{p^n}^\times \cong \Bbb{Z}/(p_1^{a_1}) \oplus \ldots \oplus \Bbb{Z}/(p_m^{a_m})
$$ where the $p_i$ are prime elements and $a_i$ are positive integers. (The $p_i$ need not be distinct).

I don't know how to go from here. I know eventually we must have that the group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/(p^n-1)$ but I don't know how that's true. Do I use the Chinese Remainder Theorem? We aren't working with coprime numbers here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the $p_i$ are all distinct, you are done by the Chinese remainder theorem. Otherwise, WLOG $p_1=p_2$. Show that in this case the polynomial $x^{p_1}-1$ has more than $p_1$ roots, which is a conradiction.

Comment: For the purposes of proving this result I would use the form with the invariant factors ($c_1,\ldots,c_d$ for you). After all, the first form implies right away that all the elements of the multiplicative group are zeros of $x^{c_k}-1=0$. As Mark explained, you can equally well show that any prime numbers can apply only once.

Comment: ^ appear, not apply. Water outage => no coffee